# How can i reword these columns and reposition the numeric component of the column name using a one-liner?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have these columns names that follow this structure in list in orig, that I am trying to rename to "new."

There are four groups of these four columns, totaling 16 columns overall. In other words, using orig as an example, columns 5-8 would contain "2" instead of 1, and columns 9-12 would contain a "3" instead of a "2", all the way up until "4". The new column names would follow the same structure, per se, but reworded and with the grouping number at the end of the name.

```
orig = [CHARGE 1 STATUTE, CHARGE 1 DESCRIPTION, CHARGE 1 TYPE, CHARGE 1 CLASS]


new = [ChrgStatute1, ChrgDesc1, ArrstngChrgFelMisd,
ArrstngChrgSvrtyOrgnl1]
```

I'm trying to accomplish this in a one-liner instead of renaming them manually using a large dictionary. I've used a combination of dictionary comprehension and replace with regex, but can't get it to work correctly. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a onliner but it's a bit unreadable. I split the logic first to show how it works, and the oneliner is at the bottom.

Note, this only works for orig list elements where the structure is `WORD NUMBER WORD`

```py
orig = ["CHARGE 1 STATUTE", "CHARGE 1 DESCRIPTION", "CHARGE 1 TYPE", "CHARGE 1 CLASS"]


# split logic for understanding
def reorder(string: str) -> str:
    return f"{string.split()[0].capitalize()}{string.split()[2].capitalize()}{string.split()[1]}"

new = []
for column in orig:
    new.append(reorder(column))
print(new)

# as oneliner:
new = [f"{string.split()[0].capitalize()}{string.split()[2].capitalize()}{string.split()[1]}" for string in orig]
print(new)
```

**output**

```py
['ChargeStatute1', 'ChargeDescription1', 'ChargeType1', 'ChargeClass1']
['ChargeStatute1', 'ChargeDescription1', 'ChargeType1', 'ChargeClass1']
```